# iText PdfSmartCopy is creating duplicate fonts

Tags: itext

I am using iText (5.5.12) `PdfSmartCopy` to merge together two files that have **embedded, unsubsetted** fonts (and happen to be generated on the same machine, so I know they are referring to the same font) in the hope that the final result will have only a single copy of the font.

However I am finding that the merged result has the font embedded twice.

### Here is the code I am using:

```
String[] srcs = ...
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(result));

document.open();
for (int i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcs[i]);
    copy.addDocument(reader);
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
}
document.close();
```

### This is the output of `pdffonts` on the relavant files:

**Input file 1:**

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TimesNewRomanPSMT                    CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes     14  0
```

**Input file 2:**

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TimesNewRomanPSMT                    CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes     11  0
```

**Output file:**

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TimesNewRomanPSMT                    CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes      3  0
TimesNewRomanPSMT                    CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes     25  0
```

Comment: `PdfSmartCopy` combines identical objects. Most likely those two font objects are not identical. For a final analysis share the pdfs, please.

Comment: I'll upload the pdfs when I get back to my machine. Though shouldn't the two fonts be identical since they are fully embedded and not subsetted (and also actually generated on the same machine -- I'll edit to add this to the question)? Or does they fonts being CID matter here? I don't really understand CID fonts. Are they compatible across pdf files, or is it like subsetted fonts which make them specific to each pdf file?

Comment: @mkl Here are the files: [file1.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/99t383hr13aiwnz/file1.pdf?dl=1), [file2.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xq8j5oif32bh21/file2.pdf?dl=1), and [merged.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9zkeppvh4nuedjv/merged.pdf?dl=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to your assumption to have

> two files that have **embedded, unsubsetted** fonts

the fonts **are** subsetted, and differently so.

From file1.pdf:

[image: from file 1]

From file2.pdf:

[image: from file 2]

As you can see there are numerous differences, there is a non-empty glyph for "1" in file 1 but not in file 2, vice versa for "2", etc...

Thus, these fonts are not identical and `PdfSmartCopy` correctly did not replace one by the other.

---

I assume that `pdffonts` did not recognize them as subsetted because they are not properly marked as subset fonts, in particular their names don't have the required subset tags and they don't have the optional **CharSet** listing of the character names defined in a font subset. Thus, the fonts not merely are not unsubsetted, the subsetting also was done incorrectly.

Thus, don't blame `pdffonts` for your incorrect assumptions but instead the PDF generator which created the input files.

Comment: As an aside, the file size of the PDFs was a dead giveaway - TimesNewRomanPSMT can hardly be compressed into a 50K or 60K PDF...

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detailed analysis. The pdf's are created from Chrome's print to PDF feature. I'm surprised they mess up the fonts so badly. I know iText does not merge subsetted fonts but do you have any recommendation for an open source tool that can?

Comment: Unfortunately no. My main pdf interests are different. I think you can use itext plus a good font processing library as framework for creating such a solution yourself, though.

Comment: @mkl Can you tell me what tool you used to analyze the pdfs/fonts and show the embedded sets? I'd like to do a similiar analysis on multiple files. Thank you.

Comment: @thewallrus *"Can you tell me what tool you used"* - On one hand a PDF internals browser like iText RUPS or PDFBox PDFDebugger to see the internal structures; in the case at hand for determining the missing subset tags and CharSet listings. On the other hand Font Forge to look into the embedded font programs.